# PowerShell RegEx with Select-String doesn't return any rows

Tags: regex, powershell

Using this reg-ex tester: http://myregextester.com/index.php
Indicates my regex should work:
Regex:

```
{name:"(\w*?)", rank:([\d]+)},
```

Sample Data to capture:

```
{name:"AARON", rank:77},
{name:"ABBEY", rank:1583},
```

Here's the powershell script I'm attempting to run , to parse json-like data into a powershell grid.

```
$regex = '{name:"(\w*?)", rank:([\d]+)},'

(Select-String -Path EmailDomains.as -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).matches |foreach {

$obj = New-Object psobject

$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Rank -Value $_.groups[1].value

$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $_.groups[0].value

$obj

} |Out-GridView -Title "Test"
```

The reg-ex never seems to return values (I'm guessing its a MS regex versus Perl regex mixup, but I can't identify), so I'm not sure what the issue could be. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark often has different functionality in different environments (in this one, I think it means "match the preceding character 0 or 1 times"). I doubt that it is the same as Perl's. Instead of

```
"(\w*?)"
```

Try:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it appears once I corrected my reg-ex, I was good to go.

Comment: The question mark in this context tells the asterisk to not be greedy.

Comment: If this were Perl, you would be correct. However, like I thought, Powershell sees a question mark as a match for 0 or 1 of the previous character. [See the doc here.](http://lab.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc137764)

Comment: It determines if a quantifier is greedy because it is placed after a quantifier. If it were not placed after a quantifier, then yes, it would make the preceding token optional.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen anything in docs as far as dual functionality of the character, do you have a doc you can point to? I've had to find annoying workarounds because I just assumed that it doesn't control greediness, that would be great if you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression:

```
(Select-String -Path EmailDomains.as -Pattern $regex -AllMatches)
```

returns an array of MatchInfo objects. The array itself does not have a Matches property.

What you have to do is expand the Matches property using the Slect-Object commandlet, then pass that along your pipeline:

```
Select-String -Path EmailDomains.as -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | select-object -expand Matches | foreach {
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears that, combined with a change in the reg-ex, brought me to where I needed to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your regex is the problem. Matches is a property on each of the objects returned by Select-Object, not on the collection of objects returned.

```
$regex = '{name:"(\w*?)", rank:([\d]+)},'
$matches = (Select-String -Path .\a.txt -Pattern $regex)

$matches | Select -ExpandProperty Matches | Select @{n="Name";e={$_.Groups[1].Value}}, @{n="Rank";e={$_.Groups[2].Value}}
```